# Java determine valid data depending on a time range

Tags: java, list, date, range

what is the best way to determine the valid attribute's value on a given day?

The table looks like this:

| Attribute name | Value | valid from |
| --- | --- | --- |
| attr1 | 41 | 01.01.2020 |
| attr1 | 41,123 | 02.02.2021 |
| attr1 | 41,456 | 02.02.2023 |

Eg. if the date is 13.06.2021, the valid value should be 41,123

And the second case is when one more row will be available:

| Attribute name | Value | valid from | valid to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| attr1 | 41 | 01.01.2020 | 01.01.2100 |
| attr1 | 41,123 | 02.02.2021 | 02.04.2021 |
| attr1 | 41,456 | 02.02.2023 | 01.01.2100 |

in this case, the valid value should be 41

Comment: Your use of "table" indicates this actually would be a SQL question instead of Java, wouldn't it? In general you'd want to remove those that start after day X or end before day X (in your second case), order by "valid from" in descending order and pick the first.

Comment: It should be Java :) I've attached the table for clarity and visualization

Comment: A `TreeMap<LocalDate, Double>` would probably do the job. But your second example is unclear because on some days you have more than one valid value.

Comment: In the second example, if the date is eg. 03.02.2021, the valid value is 41,123

Comment: @assylias could you provide any snippet or pseudocode? :)

Comment: You forgot to mention the format of your dates(It cannot be determined from your provided examples). Is it `dd.mm.yyyy` or `mm.dd.yyyy`?

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Just dropping requirements "this is what I want" isn't appreciated. When you try something yourself, and you get stuck with a specific problem, we will gladly help. But please understand that this place is not intended to give guidance with the possibly many steps required to get you from your vision to a working program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only provided the data and no code, let's assume you have a list of `Attribute` elements that look like this (simplified):

```
class Attribute {
  String name;
  double value;
  LocalDate validFrom;
  LocalDate validTo;
}
```

You ideally maintain a tree map for each attribute name which is sorted by by `validFrom`, e.g. `Map<String, SortedMap<LocalDate, Attribute>>`.

Then get the sorted map for the attribute name, get the tail or head map based on the date in question and iterate. Assuming you've sorted the map by descending `validFrom` it could look like this:

```
Map<String, SortedMap<LocalDate, Attribute>> attribs = ....;

LocalDate targetDate = LocalDate.now();


//get the map for "attr1" or an empty map if there isn't one
Iterator<Attribute> itr = attribs.getOrDefault("attr1", Collections.emptySortedMap())
       .tailMap( targetDate )
       .values()
       .iterator();

//since we have descending order we're first checking the entries that have become valid last
//so just continue until you hit one that hasn't become invalid already or you run out of entries
while(itr.hasNext()) {
  Attribute attr = itr.next();
  if(!attr.validTo.isBefore(targetDate )) {
    return attr.value;
  }
}  

//no value found, could also return an empty Optional
return null;
```

If you don't have such a map it could also be done using streams but that would be more inefficient for repeated lookups:

```
List<Attribute> attribs = ...;

LocalDate targetDate = LocalDate.now();

OptionalDouble value = 
       attribs.stream()
              .filter(a -> a.name.equals("attrib1")) //remove all other attribs
              .filter(a -> !a.validFrom.isAfter(targetDate)) //remove all that not yet valid
              .filter(a -> !a.validTo.isBefore(targetDate)) //remove all that aren't valid anymore
              .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.validFrom).reverseOrder()) //sort by validFrom in descending order to get the latest
              .mapToDouble(a -> a.value) //extract the value
              .findFirst(); //pick the first value if one exists
```